# SetUp vs Constructor in Test Fixture

Tags: c++, googletest

Why does a test fixture have a SetUp method in Google Test? Isn't the Constructor effectively the same thing? Likewise for the TearDown method. Calls to both SetUp and the Constructor, as well as TearDown and the Destructor, are consistent with the TestEventListeners: OnTestStart and OnTestEnd.

Comment: I had the same issue... link doesn't work. But I found the actual link by removing parts of the URL until it worked and then manually searching. Here is the updated link. https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/faq.md#should-i-use-the-constructordestructor-of-the-test-fixture-or-the-set-uptear-down-function

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There is [an answer to that in the FAQ](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/faq.md#should-i-use-the-constructordestructor-of-the-test-fixture-or-setupteardown-ctorvssetup):

> ### Should I use the constructor/destructor of the test fixture or the set-up/tear-down function?
>
> The first thing to remember is that googletest does **not** reuse the same test
> fixture object across multiple tests. For each `TEST_F`, googletest will create
> a **fresh** test fixture object, immediately call `SetUp()`, run the test body,
> call `TearDown()`, and then delete the test fixture object.

> When you need to write per-test set-up and tear-down logic, you have the choice
> between using the test fixture constructor/destructor or `SetUp()/TearDown()`.
> The former is usually preferred, as it has the following benefits:
>
> - By initializing a member variable in the constructor, we have the option to
>   make it `const`, which helps prevent accidental changes to its value and
>   makes the tests more obviously correct.
> - In case we need to subclass the test fixture class, the subclass'
>   constructor is guaranteed to call the base class' constructor *first*, and
>   the subclass' destructor is guaranteed to call the base class' destructor
>   *afterward*. With `SetUp()/TearDown()`, a subclass may make the mistake of
>   forgetting to call the base class' `SetUp()/TearDown()` or call them at the
>   wrong time.
>
> > You may still want to use `SetUp()/TearDown()` in the following rare cases:
>
> - In the body of a constructor (or destructor), it's not possible to use the
>   `ASSERT_xx` macros. Therefore, if the set-up operation could cause a fatal
>   test failure that should prevent the test from running, it's necessary to
>   use a `CHECK` macro or to use `SetUp()` instead of a constructor.
> - If the tear-down operation could throw an exception, you must use
>   `TearDown()` as opposed to the destructor, as throwing in a destructor leads
>   to undefined behavior and usually will kill your program right away. Note
>   that many standard libraries (like STL) may throw when exceptions are
>   enabled in the compiler. Therefore you should prefer `TearDown()` if you
>   want to write portable tests that work with or without exceptions.
> - The googletest team is considering making the assertion macros throw on
>   platforms where exceptions are enabled (e.g. Windows, Mac OS, and Linux
>   client-side), which will eliminate the need for the user to propagate
>   failures from a subroutine to its caller. Therefore, you shouldn't use
>   googletest assertions in a destructor if your code could run on such a
>   platform.
> - In a constructor or destructor, you cannot make a virtual function call on
>   this object. (You can call a method declared as virtual, but it will be
>   statically bound.) Therefore, if you need to call a method that will be
>   overridden in a derived class, you have to use `SetUp()/TearDown()`.

Comment: When are the Constructors and Destructors called in the gtest flow?

Comment: The link is now broken and I can find no mention of SetUp() vs constructor in the gtest FAQ.  This answer is quite old...any idea if the implementation has changed?

Comment: @JonnyBoy See here: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/faq.md#should-i-use-the-constructordestructor-of-the-test-fixture-or-setupteardown

Comment: Unless you are using parameterized tests then it does reuse the fixture which really sucks.

Comment: Throwing in destructor is not UB in C++. Is dangerous as if it is called during a stack unwinding will terminate the program. The user-defined destructors are `noexcept(true)` by default, but that can be overwritten. What are you referring to exactly?

Comment: Updated link: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/faq.md#should-i-use-the-constructordestructor-of-the-test-fixture-or-setupteardown-ctorvssetup

Comment: @Liger, Constructor and Destructor are called for every test case execution. The flow of execution for a TestFixture is Constructor -> SetUp ->Test fixture body  -> TearDown -> Destructor.