# Call code only once in Gtest per class

Tags: c++, googletest

I am using `gtest` as my testing framework. I am looking for a specific function that will be called only once.

So far, I have seen `SetUp` and the constructor of the class. But it seems like they are both called for each test. According to this [example](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/Primer#Writing_the_main()_Function), the constructor is where,

> You can do set-up work for each test here

leading me to believe that it's called once per test case. For the `SetUp` function,

> Code here will be called immediately after the constructor (right
>      before each test).

Does that mean both are called for each test? If so, where can I place code that will be called only once for the lifetime of the test class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SetUp vs Constructor in Test Fixture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581738/setup-vs-constructor-in-test-fixture)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Test suite setup](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#sharing-resources-between-tests-in-the-same-test-suite): `SetUpTestSuite()`.

And yes, both the constructor and SetUp() method are called for each test method. In GTest, the test functions are implemented as subclasses of the Test Case class. That's why Test Case constructor is naturally called before execution of each of its children. See this [FAQ question](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/faq.md#should-i-use-the-constructordestructor-of-the-test-fixture-or-setupteardown-ctorvssetup) about what to use: constructor or SetUp().

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. It's kinda confusing that the constructor is called multiple times.

Comment: 2nd link (FAQ question) broken

Comment: 1st link broken too

Comment: even 2nd link returns 404